# Communicate with a Running Service

Tags: c#, windows

I have a program that runs as a service on the server. It is setup this way so console of the server doesn't have to be logged in for the program to run.

I would like to create a second winform program that would talk to the service program and display any status information a GUI would normally display if the service program had a gui.

How would I talk between these two programs? They are both in C# and both under my control.

I'm not even sure what to correctly call this, so it's likely to have been already answered before.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: This has definitely been answered before. You need to perform searches to find info on this topic. When you write your code, and have questions about your code that a fair amount of web searching doesn't yield a resolution then SO is an appropriate venue to make progress towards resolving your problem(s). Please visit the SO help center for more info on writing good questions. BTW, the .NET `System.ServiceProcess` namespace is a good starting point for your web searching.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like Microsoft Message Queuing (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815811).

Your service would post messages to a queue known by your WinForms app.  You then just need to read from that queue and handle the messages as necessary.

As you control both applications, you can create your own message type and serialise/deserialise that object via MSMQ.

Answer (score 0):

Your service can override [`OnCustomCommand(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.oncustomcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) from `ServiceBase`, which allows it to recieve commands.

You can then have another application interact with your service through the [`ServiceController.ExecuteCommand()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.executecommand(v=vs.110).aspx)

In the `OnCustomCommand()` method, you will have to either if-else test the input which is an int, or use a switch statement.

e.g.

```
    protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
    {
        switch(command) 
        {
            case 128:
                 Refresh();
                 break;
            case 129:
                 WriteLog();
                 break;
      // etc
         }
    }
```

If you want two-way communication, you might need to implement a way for your service to respond. That can be message queues, writing to some database table, file, web service or something else.